# Angular 4 mobile image compression

Tags: javascript, angular, image-compression

Is there any way to make image compression fast in the mobile browser? 
For the project, I am using **Angular4** as frontend framework and using **ng2ImgMax** for compression image. [tutorial link](https://alligator.io/angular/resizing-images-in-browser-ng2-img-max/)

The time taken for compression in **the Desktop browser** is approx 1 sec, whereas for **mobile browser** time taken is relatively **too high**. It would take **more than 15 sec for compression an image of 3MB**.
**Is there a way possible to speed up the mobile javascript?**

Comment: How did you solve this problem?